# Gitlab-CI: Specify that Job C should run after Job B if Job A fails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Imagine you have the following Pipeline:

```
Job A (deploy) -> Job B (test) -> Job C (remove test deployment)
```

The pipeline should deploy a test image and test it after a successful deployment. After the test I want to run a cleanup script regardless of the test output, but only if the test image (Job A) was deployed.

To summarize this:  I want Gitlab to execute Job C only if Job A succeeds, **but after Job B**.

Things that won't work:

- `when: on-failure` (Job A or Job B could failed, but only Job A is important)
- `when: always` (maybe Job A failed which causes Job C to fail)
- `when: on-success` (requires all jobs to succeed)

I know that GitLab has a feature called DAG Pipelines which allow you to specify multiple dependencies on other jobs with the `needs` keyword, but sadly the `when` keyword is always scoped to all prior jobs. So you are not able to say something like:

```yaml
when:
    on-success: job-a
    always: job-b
```

Do I miss something or is there no way to achieve such a behaviour?

Comment: To clarify - you _want_ Job B (testing job) to run even if Job A (deployment) fails?

Comment: No, it should be skipped. I want to run Job C after Job B has passed or failed. But Job A should have passed.

Answer (score 57):

The `needs` DAG field can be used to conditionally execute the cleanup (Job C), if Job B fails or succeeds, but NOT when it is *skipped* because Job A failed.

Create 2 cleanup jobs that match the following boolean conditions:

- `(Job A succeeds and Job B succeeds)`: If all previous tasks succeed (Job A and Job B), we can run the cleanup with `when: on_success`. However, this will *not* trigger if Job A succeeds and Job B fails.
- `(Job A succeeds and Job B fails)`: To circumvent the previous scenario with an untriggered cleanup (Job C), we make use of the fact that if Job B fails, this implies that Job A succeeded in the pipeline. By creating a duplicate cleanup task and specifying a `needs` tag on Job B and `when: on_failure`, the cleanup task will only run if Job A succeeds and Job B fails.

To reiterate: a cleanup job will run if `(Job A succeeds and Job B succeeds)` or `(Job A succeeds and Job B fails)`, which by boolean expression reduction is equivalent to `(Job A succeeds)`.

An obvious caveat here is that there are now 2 cleanup jobs that are displayed in the pipeline; however, they are mutually exclusive and only one could ever be executed.

Here is a sample configuration:

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - test
  - cleanup

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployed
    - "true"
  when: always

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo Executing tests
    - "true"
  when: on_success

# a YAML anchor reduces repetition
.cleanup_job: &cleanup_job
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - echo Cleaned up deployment

cleanup_deployment_success:
  when: on_success
  <<: *cleanup_job

cleanup_deployment_failure:
  needs: ["test_job"]
  when: on_failure
  <<: *cleanup_job
```

---

With various intentional fail conditions, the following pipeline states are produced:

- **failed pipeline**: [image: Job A succeeds and Job B fails]
- **failed pipeline**: [image: Job A fails and Job B is skipped]
- **passed pipeline**: [image: Job A succeeds and Job B succeeds]

Logically, this indicates that regardless of whether Job B succeeded or failed, Job C runs if Job A succeeded. Furthermore, the failure state is preserved in the overall pipeline.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the pipeline to be in passed state, even if the tests have failed? I want the pipeline to be in failed state if one job fails.

Comment: @Sebi2020 Unfortunately, it seems so. If a job fails but the pipeline "passes", an orange-ish exclamation point with "passed" is used instead of a green checkmark "passed". I have updated my answer to demonstrate what that looks like. The `when` condition triggers are not very elaborate in GitLab CI. I will take another look and see if I can resolve the pipeline fail state, but I have some serious doubts.

Comment: @Sebi2020 I updated my answer to exploit DAGs and the `needs` tag. Let me know if this satisfies your constraints/conditions.

Comment: This is a workaround, i already have had this idea. but I have hoped that there is a cleaner way to achieve that, because this needs duplication of the same job just to circumvent the absent "when job scope".

Comment: @Sebi2020 Unfortunately, GitLab's CI system is _very_ rigid it its approach to pipelines. For this specified 3 stage pipeline, the only caveat here is a duplicate skipped cleanup job shows up in the pipeline. If I find another solution, I will update my answer. However, after reading documentation for over an hour, I am not particularly convinced there will be a cleaner solution until GitLab adds more advanced matching for the `when` tag. More often than not, most of my GitLab CI configurations end up with dirty solutions/hacks due to their disinterest in supporting non-trivial use cases.

Comment: This is close to what I need - @concision have you found a way to have the stage flow pictured in the 1st image (pass > fail > pass) and yet mark the pipeline as passed?

Comment: @GrayedFox If there is, I am not aware of it. However, you may be able to hack something together where instead of failing job B, mark it passed and set a flag that job C can use to determine if it should NO-OP.

Comment: Great minds my friend. Currently attempting to use artifacts:when:always to store the exit code of the test script and output that to a build.env file so I can read the result in the next job. If it works I will post an answer here too. I like GitLab but my lord this is janky.

Comment: What if I need to do this for "container_scanning" job for container scans provided by GitLab security? For example, the image tag that I use for the built image in the package stage depends on the commit SHA for a regular commit and the tag for a release. With container scanning, I must define the job name as "container_scanning" and specify the docker image and its tag (commit SHA or commit tag) as the `DOCKER_IMAGE` variable of the job. What should I do in this scenario?

Answer (score 7):

> The needs DAG field can be used to conditionally execute the cleanup (Job `C`), if Job `B` fails or succeeds, but NOT when it is skipped because Job `A` failed.

That might have changed with [GitLab 13.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#optional-dag-needs-jobs-in-cicd-pipelines) (April 2021)

> ### Optional DAG ('needs:') jobs in CI/CD pipelines
>
> The directed acyclic graph (DAG) in GitLab CI/CD lets you use the `needs` syntax to configure a job to start earlier than its stage (as soon as dependent jobs complete). >
> We also have the `rules`, `only`, or `except` keywords, which determine if a job is added to a pipeline at all.
>
> Unfortunately, if you combine `needs` with these other keywords, it’s possible that your pipeline could fail when a dependent job does not get added to a pipeline.
>
> In this release, we are adding the `optional` keyword to the `needs` syntax for DAG jobs.
>
> - If a dependent job is marked as `optional` but *not* present in the pipeline, the `needs` job ignores it.
> - If the job is `optional` and present in the pipeline, the `needs` job waits for it to finish before starting.
>
> This makes it much easier to safely combine `rules`, `only`, and `except` with the growing popularity of DAG.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_11/optional.png -- Optional DAG ('needs:') jobs in CI/CD pipelines]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#optional-needs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30680).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another alternative. I am currently looking to implement this exact use case for e2e-tests and my preference will probably be to delay the reporting of test results by using artifacts. The setup would be something like this:

```
Job A (deploy) -> Job B (run test, collect results into artifact) -> Job C (undeploy) -> Job D (publish test results from artifact)
```

Job B would be configured to always be successful, and only save its findings as an artifact (e.g. JUnit xml). Job D would then publish the results and the pipeline would fail here if tests were unsuccessful. This should preserve pipeline failure state, even if Job C and Job D run unconditionally with the previously mentioned technique of duplicating the Job with multiple `when:` conditions.