# Git CI/CD variable to get the number of commits behind in merge request pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Need to fail the pipeline in case if the source branch is behind in commits with the target branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [issue 15310](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/15310) and [GitLab 11.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2018/12/22/gitlab-11-6-released/#run-cicd-for-merge-requests) (Dec. 2018), you can run a pipeline only if it is a `merge_request`.

That allows you to access [`$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) predefined variable, that you can then use in [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#use-rules-to-run-pipelines-for-merge-requests) (like ones defined in the [`gitlab/ci/templates/Workflows/MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Workflows/MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml).
In your case, a rule specific to test if new commits are added:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  script: ./test
  only:
    - merge_requests
  rules:    
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

However, a `if` rule would not allow executing the kind of [script `git` command you would need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526591/6309):

```
 git merge-base --is-ancestor <maybe-ancestor-commit> <descendant-commit>
 git merge-base --is-ancestor $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA
```

If that commands returns 0 (true), the job should process, and the target branch HEAD is an ancestor of the merge request branch, which means the latter only brings new commits directly on top of the former (target) branch.

So I would still have a job running only for `merge_requests`, executing in a `script:` directive that `git` command, and calling your actual script (the one you want to see executed on merge-request "in case if the source branch is behind in commits with the target branch") in a *separate* stage (called by the first gatekeeper one), using [`needs: <first-stage>`, as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67237412/6309).

Comment: But the target and source SHA could be retrieved only when the merge results pipeline is enabled. Is there any possibility without enabling it running the pipeline only in the source branch.

Comment: @Aswathshobi you can do the same with branch names instead of SHA1.